# Website with large list and detail iframe, annoying to use (browser solution?)

Tags: browser, website

I use a third party content management system with a **list** of content on the left and a **detail** view iframe at the top on the right. The list can be very large - ten "page downs", say - and when I click an item far down in the list I have to hit HOME to scoot back up to the top of the page to view the detail in the detail view. Then I page down x times to get back to where I was in the list.

Short of asking the owner to redevelop the page to make the detail iframe float and follow the user around the page, does anyone have any suggestions for what I could do to augment the viewing experience? For example, does any browser support an extra dummy/clone view, i.e. a function that loads another static *view* of the current page, allowing for two views of the same page, linked to one another? I used to play a game that supported this function, it was essentially like placing a camera over part of the game world, and being able to move anywhere else in the main view but always maintaining the extra little static view. Picture in picture effect.

Sorry for the vagueness, hopefully you get where I'm going.

Comment: You can always hit the HOME button to move to the top of the page in the iframe. Click in an iframe, and you effectively select it, so shortcuts will work (tested with FireFox)

Comment: Thanks for suggestions... I'm unsure. I can't rebuild the page, it's a 3rd party database-driven site, very locked down. The iframe is static, too... it just loads the detail depending on which list item I click. So, I can click the HOME button to scoot back to the top of the list (and see the iframe), and then I use page down to get back to where I was in the list.

Comment: Are you talking about the "Home" key on your keyboard, or some "Home" button within the web app itself?  If you want to change the pages in (only) your browser, have you looked into using something like [GreaseMonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey)?

Comment: Thanks guys, Greasemonkey, I've set it up and am investigating, see if I can get it to do what I want.